# add my nuxt pages to my vue laravel app ( how connect these two)

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, nuxt.js

i have vue and laravel project . for ssr issue i had to code 3 pages of my project in nuxt . Is  there a way to connect the nuxt 3 pages with whole my vue laravel project?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.
Nuxt is a framework by itself and it cannot be merged with another Vue + Laravel framework. You can probably look for alternatives like https://prerender.io/vue-js/

Or add SSR to Vue manually: https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/#installation

Even tho, I'm not sure this will behave in Laravel nor if you can do it directly with PHP maybe.